# Gradle how to turn a flat directory of massive amount of jar files to the .m2/repository structure?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, repository

I wonder how can I quickly take a directory in my computer that contains 1K jars, and let Gradle structure it to the Maven `.m2/repository` structure. I've read of the [Gradle publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#publishing_maven) feature, but it seems pretty impossible to use when the amount of jars is that big because they are not taking the information from the META-INF, but want the user to specify the group ID and other details.

Comment: Which platform do you run? I would suggest doing it with a bash script, to be honest. However for Windows I cannot come up with a solution due to my lack of competence in Win scripting .

Comment: A script would be fine. A solution like you suggest is exactly what I'm looking for, even though it sounds weird that the Java ecosystem wouldn't offer an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you wait a little, however I come up with a solution at this point. Have a look at this bash script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
PWD=$( pwd )
JARS=$( find $PWD -name '*.jar' )
for JARFILE in $JARS
do
    echo "found JAR: $JARFILE";
    mkdir -p $PWD/extracted/$JARFILE/;
    unzip $JARFILE -d $PWD/extracted/ &> /dev/null;
    if [ -d "$PWD/extracted/META-INF/maven/" ]; then
        POMPROPS=$( find $PWD/extracted/META-INF/maven -name 'pom.properties' );
        echo "found POMPROPS: $POMPROPS";
        POMXML=$( find $PWD/extracted/META-INF/maven -name 'pom.xml' );
        echo "found POMXML: $POMXML";
        ARTIFACTID=$( grep 'artifactId' $POMPROPS | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\r' );
        GROUPID=$( grep 'groupId' $POMPROPS | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\r' );
        VERSION=$( grep 'version' $POMPROPS | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\r' );
        if [[ -f $POMPROPS && -f $POMXML ]]; then
            GROUPDIR=$( sed 's/\./\//g' <<<$GROUPID);
            echo "Group dir: "$GROUPDIR;
            mkdir -p ~/.m2test/repository/$GROUPDIR/$ARTIFACTID/$VERSION/
            cp $POMXML ~/.m2test/repository/$GROUPDIR/$ARTIFACTID/$VERSION/$ARTIFACTID-$VERSION.pom
            cp $JARFILE ~/.m2test/repository/$GROUPDIR/$ARTIFACTID/$VERSION/$ARTIFACTID-$VERSION.jar
        else
            echo "did not find pom properties and/or xml "
            echo "$JARFILE: did not find pom properties and/or xml" >> log.txt
        fi
    else
        echo "$JARFILE: no maven directory found" >> log.txt
    fi
    rm -rf $PWD/extracted/;
done
```

First have a look at it and understand it, please. You should not run any script, without understanding it. Of course I don't want to screw you, but always be cautious . You must have sed, grep and unzip installed. However most distributions should have that on board.

Just run that script, when in a terminal inside of the directory. It should organize your JARs inside of `~/.m2test`. If some files were not found, it will be logged inside `log.txt`. Eventually, you can copy-paste or move the files from `~/.m2test` to `~/.m2` as soon, as you are optimistic, it worked out.

And of course: Always do make backups (of your `~/.m2` in this case) !

This - of course - only works, if your JARs have that `maven` directory in `META-INF`. If it doesn't, I don't have a better guess, how to organize it into the local repository.